# ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> returns same values when adding different elements to it

Tags: java, arraylist, permutation

I need to add List of permutation to ArrayList type but for me when I try to run below code then I am getting same value repeated. Please help me here.

```
public static void permutation(ArrayList<Integer> perm, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> solution, int index) {
        if (index >= perm.size()) {
            solution.add(perm);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = index; i < perm.size(); i++) {
            Collections.swap(perm, index, i);
            permutation(perm, solution, index + 1);
            Collections.swap(perm, index, i);
        }

    }
```

if passed [1,2,3] as first argument.
Expected output: [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]] should be added to second argument.
Actual output: [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

Comment: I'll give you a clue but not the answer as I think this is a homework (its Sunday night after all). For this you will need a non recursive nested loop solution and also the inner lists likely needs at least shallow cloning. If you must use recursion which would be ok but more difficult, then you must clone the inner lists or else every element of the outer list will be pointing to the same instance of the first inner list in memory.

Comment: will try with non-recursive solution as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that

```
solution.add(perm);
```

does not add a copy of `perm` to `solution` - it only adds a reference to `perm`. You are changing the contents `perm` after that line, which means that whatever seems to have been added to `solution` also changes (because it is the same object).

What you need to do instead is to add a copy of `perm` to the `solution`.

In your case the simplest way to create such a copy is by creating a `new ArrayList<Integer>(perm)`:

```
solution.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(perm));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

public class GetAllPermutations {

```
public static void getPermutations(int[] array){  
    helper(array, 0);  
}  

private static void helper(int[] array, int pos){  
    if(pos >= array.length - 1){   
        System.out.print("[");  
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){  
            System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");  
        }  
        if(array.length > 0)   
            System.out.print(array[array.length - 1]);  
        System.out.println("]");  
        return;  
    }  

    for(int i = pos; i < array.length; i++){   
      
        int t = array[pos];  
        array[pos] = array[i];  
        array[i] = t;  

        helper(array, pos+1);  

        t = array[pos];  
        array[pos] = array[i];  
        array[i] = t;  
    }  
}  
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3};  
    getPermutations(numbers);  
}
```

}

Comment: ***Output will be:***
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]

Note:
Instead of printing in system console you can add it to your list

Comment: Cool...nice solution!